# Sorting integer value in php

Tags: php, sorting, variables

I have 19 variables in a php file.

```
$a = 20;
$b = 23;
$c = 2;
$d = 92;
$e = 51;
$f = 27;
$g = 20;
$h = 20;
.....
.....
$s = 32;
```

What i need, I need to show only top 5 value. And there is similar value for some variables. In that case, I need to show the first value only if it is in the top 5 value.

I am not having any clue on doing this.

After receiving  some feedback given bellow, i have used array and asort 
Here is the example-

```
<?php
$fruits = array("a" => "32", "b" => "12", "c" => "19", "d" => "18");
asort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
?>
```

The output looks like this:

```
b = 12 d = 18 c = 19 a = 32
```

I need the reverse result. Meaning, 32, 19, 18, 12.....

Any help. Just dont know the exact command

Comment: Do you need to show the variable name and its value, or only the values?

Comment: stick them in an array then [asort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) it

Comment: Individual variables for values that have to be evaluated in aggregate is often not a good solution. An array data structure is quite a lot easier to work with.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: I need to echo values only. and they are integer.

Comment: @Kalid And are your variables always sequential `$a` through `$s`?

Comment: Despite of two loud suggestions that you should use array, I here by do that again. Please!! Use an array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is best done by putting the values of the variables into an array and running

`sort($arr);` (this is from lowes to highest).

`rsort($arr);` sorts high to low.
 http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Then you can get the first values at array-index 0,1,2,3 and 4 which will be the biggest numbers.

So:

```
$arr= array ($a,$b,$c, ....);
rsort($arr);
var_dump($arr); // gives the output.

$arr[0] // biggest number
$arr[4] // 5th biggest number.
```

Answer (score 3):

A funny way to do this:

```
$a = 20;
$b = 23;
$c = 2;
$d = 92;
$e = 51;
$f = 27;
$g = 20;
$h = 20;

$array = compact(range('a', 'h'));
rsort($array);

foreach(array_slice($array, 0, 5) as $top) {
    echo $top, "\n";
}
```

Output

```
92 
51 
27 
23 
20
```

Demo: http://3v4l.org/Wi8q7

Comment: I knew about extract, but not compact, nice! and there was me fiddling with decimal char codes :)

Comment: Never happens to use it, so it doesn't matter!

Answer (score 2):

Do they need to be individual variables? Storing the values in an array is a better option. So, either manually put all the variables into an array, or change your structure to something more like:

```
$arr = array(
    'a' = 20,
    'b' = 23,
    'c' = 2,
    'd' = 92,
    'e' = 51,
     ....
     ....
    's' => 32
);
```

or similar. Then use [**sort()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) to sort the array:

```
sort($arr);
```

To get the top 5, use [**array_slice()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
$arr = array_slice($arr, 0, 5);
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/0kfxIj2Q)

*Note: sort() may not be best option for you depending on the desired result. For other sorting options, consult the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php*

Answer (score 0):

```
$array=array();
for ($i=97;$i<=115;$i++){ //decimal char codes for a-s
  $var =chr($i);
  $array[]= $$var;  //variable variable $a- $s
}

asort($array);
var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
  array_push($data,$a);
  array_push($data,$b);
  .
  .
  .
  $sorted_array  = usort($data, 'mysort');
  $top5 = array_splice($sorted_array,5);
  if(in_array($your_variable,$top5)){
     return $top5[0];
  }else {
     return $top5;
  } 
  function mysort($a,$b){
      if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? 1 : -1;
  }
 ?>
```